# KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<myClass>> & UI not updating

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I'm just trying to get a very simple example to work but I can't figure out why the objects inside my ObservableArray are not being updated. The array itself is observable and works (i.e. the UI is updated when adding new items to the array), but changing the items in the array themselves don't get reflected in the UI, but I don't know why as I have marked everything as observable...

I cannot find many examples with Typescript hence my question... what am I doing wrong? When calling setEditMode from the UI the values change, but the UI doesn't...

I thought about using knockout.mapping but I would prefer to have my "exportador" class created to see how everything fits rather than having something created for me.

I know this has been asked a few times but no one of the answers given has been useful for this problem...

Thanks a lot.

This is my .ts file:

```
/// <reference path="typings/require/require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/knockout.mapping/knockout.mapping.d.ts" />

import ko = require('knockout')
import $ = require('jquery');

class exportador {
    public exportadorId: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    public nombre: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    public telefono: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    public mode: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    static fromJson(data: any) {
        return new exportador(data.ExportadorId, data.Nombre, data.Telefono);
    }

    constructor(id: number, nom: string, telef: string) {
        this.exportadorId = ko.observable(id);
        this.nombre = ko.observable(nom);
        this.telefono = ko.observable(telef);
        this.mode = ko.observable("display");
    }


    setEditMode() {
        this.mode = ko.observable<string>("edit");
    }

    setDisplayMode() {
        this.mode = ko.observable<string>("display");
    }    
}

class exportadorViewModel {
    public exportadores: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<exportador>>;
    public currentPage: KnockoutObservable<number>;


    crearNuevoExportador()
    {
        var exp = new exportador(-1, "", "");
        this.exportadores.push(ko.observable<exportador>(exp));
    }

    constructor() {
        this.exportadores = ko.observableArray<KnockoutObservable<exportador>>([]);
        this.currentPage = ko.observable(-1);
    }
}

require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = new exportadorViewModel();

    $.getJSON("/api/exportadores",function (data: any) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, item => {
                var x = ko.observable<exportador>(exportador.fromJson(item));
                viewModel.exportadores.push(x);
            });
        });

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});


});
```

Comment: How does the generated js look ? Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three issues with the code you posted.  First, you should use plain objects inside of the KnockoutObservableArray, instead of wrapping them in another KnockoutObservable.  Use:

```
public exportadores: KnockoutObservableArray<exportador>;
```

instead of:

```
public exportadores: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<exportador>>;
```

Second, is that it's not meaningful to try to apply a type when calling ko.observable.  (This is where you're calling actual js code, which doesn't know about the types, rather than making use of a typescript defined interface).  So use:

```
this.mode = ko.observable("edit");
```

instead of:

```
this.mode = ko.observable<string>("edit");
```

Finally, you're going to have problems with the meaning of 'this' the way your methods are defined.  You can get around the issue using the 'fat arrow' syntax, so you want to define them like:

```
setEditMode = () => {
    this.mode = ko.observable("edit");
};
```

instead of:

```
setEditMode() {
    this.mode = ko.observable<string>("edit");
}
```

Overall, your code should look like this:

```
class exportador {
    public exportadorId: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    public nombre: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    public telefono: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    public mode: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    static fromJson(data: any) {
        return new exportador(data.ExportadorId, data.Nombre, data.Telefono);
    }

    constructor(id: number, nom: string, telef: string) {
        this.exportadorId = ko.observable(id);
        this.nombre = ko.observable(nom);
        this.telefono = ko.observable(telef);
        this.mode = ko.observable("display");
    }


    setEditMode = () => {
        this.mode = ko.observable("edit");
    };

    setDisplayMode = () => {
        this.mode = ko.observable("display");
    }    
}

class exportadorViewModel {
    public exportadores: KnockoutObservableArray<exportador>;
    public currentPage: KnockoutObservable<number>;

    crearNuevoExportador()
    {
        var exp = new exportador(-1, "", "");
        this.exportadores.push(exp);
    }

    constructor() {
        this.exportadores = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.currentPage = ko.observable(-1);
    }
}

require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = new exportadorViewModel();

        $.getJSON("/api/exportadores", function (data: any) {
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, item => {
                    var x = exportador.fromJson(item);
                    viewModel.exportadores.push(x);
                });
            });

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });    
});
```

I noticed a fourth issue after submitting my answer.  You are assigning a new observable to 'mode' instead of just updating the value that it contains.  Outside of the initial declaration in the constructor, you should update them like this:

```
    setEditMode = () => {
        this.mode("edit");
    };

    setDisplayMode = () => {
        this.mode("display");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact the real issue with my code was your 4th issue, the bit about assigning this.mode to a new value rather than updating it in the setEditMode / setDisplayMode. This did the trick. :-)

I have also changed the rest of the code to remove the observables inside the array as it looks easier to read (I only started adding it because I was going crazy! but it works with or withour it - which btw I don't understand :)

But it is sorted now. Many thanks.